# How to communicate with CEF via Sockets

Tags: delphi, indy, chromium-embedded, tchromium

How can I communicate with `CEF` via `Indy` Sockets through `Remote debugging protocol`?
As described here: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/debugger-protocol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a Proof of Concept for DWS (pascal to javascript compilation, as used in Smart Mobile Studio) some time ago:
https://code.google.com/p/asmprofiler/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2F-Other-%2FRemoteDebuggerDWS

You can use my Indy 10 websocket (and socket.io!) components from here:
https://github.com/andremussche/DelphiWebsockets

Comment: Wow amazing! Is it possible to protect the chrome server somehow? Via password?

Comment: @user3060326: AFAIK no (only enable debugging stuff when developing and not in production)

Comment: You can use `--remote-debugging-socket-name` but I don't know this works. Socket name vs Port number?

Answer (score 1):

The API currently requires using the WebSocket protocol which is not supported in Indy. The API documentation page contains this note:

> Note that we are currently working on exposing an HTTP-based protocol
>   that does not require client WebSocket implementation.

There are WebSocket client libraries available for Delphi both free and commercial (some use Indy as their internal TCP library).

You will also need a JSON library, available in newer Delphi versions and also as free open source (for example SuperObject and lkJSON).